# Trouble importing Excel fields into Python via Pandas - index out of bounds error

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, text

I'm not sure what happened, but my code has worked today, however not it won't.  I have an Excel spreadsheet of projects I want to individually import and put into lists.  However, I'm getting a "IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8" error and Google searches have not resolved this for me.  Any help is appreciated. I have the following fields in my Excel sheet: id, funding_end, keywords, pi, summaryurl, htmlabstract, abstract, project_num, title.  Not sure what I'm missing...

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_excel('new_ahrq_projects_current.xlsx',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
df = df[df.columns[cols]]

tt = df['funding_end'] = df['funding_end'].astype(str)
tt = df.funding_end.tolist()
for t in tt:
   allenddates.append(t)

bb = df['keywords'] = df['keywords'].astype(str)
bb = df.keywords.tolist()
for b in bb:
   allkeywords.append(b)

uu = df['pi'] = df['pi'].astype(str)
uu = df.pi.tolist()
for u in uu:
   allpis.append(u)

vv = df['summaryurl'] = df['summaryurl'].astype(str)
vv = df.summaryurl.tolist()
for v in vv:
   allsummaryurls.append(v)

ww = df['htmlabstract'] = df['htmlabstract'].astype(str)
ww = df.htmlabstract.tolist()
for w in ww:
   allhtmlabstracts.append(w) 

xx = df['abstract'] = df['abstract'].astype(str)
xx = df.abstract.tolist()
for x in xx:
   allabstracts.append(x) 

yy = df['project_num'] = df['project_num'].astype(str)
yy = df.project_num.tolist()
for y in yy:
   allprojectnums.append(y)    

zz = df['title'] = df['title'].astype(str)
zz = df.title.tolist()

for z in zz:
   alltitles.append(z)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IndexError: **index out of bounds** means you're trying to insert or access **something** which is beyond its limit or range.

Every time, when you load either of these files such as an `test.xlx`, `test.csv` or `test.xlsx` file using **Pandas** such as:

```
data_set = pd.read_excel('file_example_XLS_10.xls', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

It would be better for everyone to find the **length of columns** of a DataFrame that will help you move forward when working with **large Data_Sets**. e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

data_set = pd.read_excel('file_example_XLS_10.xls', encoding="ISO-8859-1") 
data_frames = pd.DataFrame(data_set)

print("Length of Columns:", len(data_frames.columns))
```

This will give you the **exact number of columns** of an Excel Spread-Sheet. Then you can specify the Data Frames Accordingly:

> Length of Columns: 8
>
> cols = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

Answer (score 3):

> "IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8"

```
cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

should be `cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

I think you have 8 columns but your col has 9 col index.

Comment: I just double checked and unfortunately I have 9 columns.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Bill CX that it sounds like you're trying to access a column that doesn't exist. Although I cannot reproduce your error, I have some ideas that may help you move forward.

First, double check the shape of your data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_excel('new_ahrq_projects_current.xlsx',encoding="ISO-8859-1")
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
print(df.shape) # print shape of data read in to python
```

The output should be

```
(X, 9) # "X" is the number of rows
```

If the data frame has 8 columns, then the `df.shape` will be `(X, 8)`. This could be why your are getting the error.

Another check for you is to print out the first few rows of your data frame.

```
print(df.head)
```

This will let you double-check to see if you have read in the data in the correct form.  I'm not sure, but it might be possible that your `.xlsx` file has 9 columns, but pandas is reading in only 8 of them.